# Can Guitar Hero Warriors of Rock (PS3) peripherals work with Rock Band 4 (PS4)?

Tags: rock-band-4, guitar-hero-warriors-rock

So the questions says it all. I have GH WoR peripherals (Guitar, drums, mic) and would like to use them in Rock Band 4.

I know this [comptability chart](http://forums.harmonixmusic.com/discussion/258920/the-rock-band-4-instrument-compatibility-chart) exists, and it says that the guitar should work, and the mic is like any universal mic.

But what bothers me is the drums. The guitar hero drums has 5 "buttons" while the RB type has only 4. However, I was wondering if anyone has experience using them (Even with some dongle or something) and can verify if that's possible, or a new set of items is needed (I know they don't make them anymore)